# Stack overflow error when adding a member to a class in huge solution

Tags: c++, class, stack-overflow

Please look at this code:

```
class A
{
int a;
};
```

Then add one more member to class A:

```
class A
{
int a;
int b;
};
```

In my huge solution when I add one more member to a class (like member b in class A) I get stack overflow error. I assume that this is somehow related to writing to not reserved data adresses.

Is there any way to find such places in visual studio? Any better ideas why such kind of error happens?

Comment: Is the membre you add really an `int`?

Comment: Look for places where you access objects of class `A` via pointers. Turn on all compiler warnings. Use a memory debugger (on Linux "valgrind" is great for such things). Or just use your debugger to see where the error occurs.

Comment: Another thing that can cause that to happen is if you create very large arrays on the stack.

Comment: Seth Carnegie: error happens when I add any variable of any type and in any quantity. I think I'm very lucky not getting the error so long time.

Comment: Kerrek SB: I used visual studio debugger and I can see where the code crushed, but from that I cannot make any suggestions which module in my soluttion really causes that error. I will try to use memory debugger.

Comment: -1 silly question. reproduce the behavior in as small a program as possible and repost

Comment: Alf P. Steinbach: beliewe me that the reproduction is really impossible! I have too much modules that depend much on each other and reproduction will be some impossible thing to do.

Comment: @Vadim: When you have the crash in the debugger, can't you do a backtrace to find the function in which the crash occurred?

Comment: @Vadim: Show the code that is using the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first question: Are you really adding an `int`? If yes, then this answer is applicable.

This can happen when:

- Your class is so enormous that it's constructor will cause a stack overflow because it can not allocate enough memory on the stack to allocate memory for all members.
- You are doing pointer arithmic somewhere that fails when you add a member.
- You are creating an huge array on the stack of this object that becomes too large when you add this member.

I would suggest you supply us with some more relevant information (platform, compiler, real code/class definition) first.

Comment: Or if you are allocating a huge stack array of this 1 class for example.

Comment: Vadim: Please use `std::vector`s or `new`/`delete` to avoid this problem.

Comment: I hightly apologize for what I have written as solved: the issue is not solved... I'm using new/delete and get the error. I reduced size of arrays and I still get error. I think code snippets are not possible because they are too big to post as there are too much classes...

Comment: @Vadim: Post the parts where you add the members to the classes.

Comment: nightcracker: please let me some more time to check this stuff with arrays, than I will write what I get, and post some code snippet. Please be patient.

Comment: Ok, I double checked my code: indeed the problem was in big array, I created such one for reason it was easier and faster, but luckily I was able to reduce size of the array 8 times down, so now I'm not getting error. Thanks everybody for help!